# What is the real frequency received by the first ship?

Tags: doppler-effect

[image]I do not undrestand the answer of the following question:

> From the first ship which is at rest, sound frequency of 7600Hz is produced and it is reflected by the second ship,moving away from the first ship with velocity 40 m/s what is the frequency received by the first ship?

The answer which I found in a book is use of doppler effect twice as follows:

frequency received by second ship is  f'=7600×(340-40)/340 and frequency received  back by the first is f=[340/(340+40)]×f'=6000
I dont undrestand why we must use doppler effect twice,I think the answer is f'=7600×(340-40)/340=6705 not 6000 because there is no need to consider the second ship as a sourse again ,it's work is just reflecting the taps of waves it receives, there is no time interval between receiving a tap of wave and reflecting it for the second ship. The moment it receives a tap of wave ,reflects it, so time intervals for emitting these reflected taps of wave is equal to time interval between receiving these taps of wave by the second ship, so the second ship can not be considered as a source for the first ship again and the frequency can not change after reflecting from the second ship.it reflects what it receives. Besides, I have added my calculation of what I think is correct. Which part of it is wrong?
 Would you please correct me if I am wrong about it and explain it clearly?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that is is sound that you are writing about?

Ship 1 is the stationary ship emitting sound of frequency $f$ and wavelength $\lambda$ and ship 2 is the one moving away from ship 1 at a speed $v$.
$f\lambda = c$ where $c$ is the speed of sound relative to the air.

If ship 2 had not been moving then in one second it would have received $f$ waves.
However since it is moving away from ship 1 in one second it will receive $f - \dfrac v \lambda = f'$ waves $\Rightarrow f' = \dfrac {(c-v)f}{c} $.

These sound waves hit ship 2 and so the frequency of the waves emitted by ship 2 is $f'$.

However as the ship is moving the separation between crests will increase and so in one second $f'$ waves will be emitted and they will occupy a distance $c+v$.
Their wavelength is $\lambda'' = \dfrac{c+v}{f'}= \dfrac {c}{f''}$ where $f''$ is the frequency which will be received by ship 1.

$f'' = \dfrac {cf'}{c+v} = \dfrac {c-v}{c+v}f$

You can think of the atoms making up the hull of ship 2 being excited by an incoming frequency of $f'$ and re radiating sound of exactly the same frequency but those atoms now constitute a moving source.

Comment: I added the calculation of my thought , would you please check it and find the mistake  . Your comparison was not clear enough

Comment: What @Farcher says is correct, except he apparently misread the situation in the question, so I suspect that that is confusing you.  He has the moving ship as the source of the sound and also as the receiver of the reflected sound, with the stationary ship reflecting the sound.  And he has the moving ship moving toward the stationary ship rather than away.

Comment: @D.Ennis  +1 and very many thanks.  I need you as my proof reader! :-)  I will rewrite my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think it will be clearer to you if you think in terms of sine waves being received and reflected, rather than "taps."

The second thing is to be sure that you understand that the effect on the observed frequency for an observer moving away from the source is not quite equivalent to the effect on the observed frequency when the source is moving away from the observer.    That's why the equations are different.   When the observer moves away, the wavelength stays the same, but the observer's speed is subtracted from the speed of sound, So it's $v$ that changes in the equation $f = \frac{v}{\lambda}$.    When the source moves away, the wavelength it produces becomes longer but the speed of sound stays the same, so it's $\lambda$ that changes in the equation $f = \frac{v}{\lambda}$.

If the moving away ship were just an observer it would receive the frequency as lowered by the Doppler effect with modified $v$.   If the moving away ship were just the source, then the stationary ship would hear the frequency lowered by the Doppler effect with the modified $\lambda$.   But both of those things are happening.   Picture the moving ship as running away from the sine wave, so the peaks of the wave occur less frequently, AND picture the late-arriving peak being reflected over a time interval as the ship moves away, stretching the reflected wavelength.